# Show and Hide Stacklayout using button on clicked

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a dynamic control where being created when the page is loaded, however, I wanted to include a button also wherein it has a capability to show and hide the stack layout whenever I click it, but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly, please see my code.

```
                StackLayout commentStack = new();

            var button = new Button();
            button.Text = "+ Add a Comment";
            button.WidthRequest = 100;
            button.Clicked += (sender, e) => OnButtonClicked(commentStack);

            var stackGrid = new Grid()
            {
                RowDefinitions = new()
                {
                    new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Auto) },
                    new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Auto) },
                    new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Auto) },
                },
                ColumnDefinitions = new()
                {
                    new ColumnDefinition(),
                }
            };

            var commentlabel = new Label();
            commentlabel.Text = Translator.Section_Comments;
            commentlabel.FontSize = 17;
            commentlabel.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;

            var frame = new Frame();
            var editor = new Editor();

            frame.BorderColor = Color.LightGray;
            frame.Padding = 1;
            frame.HasShadow = false;

            editor.IsEnabled = !this.IsReadOnly;
            editor.FontSize = 17;
            editor.HeightRequest = 150;

            editor.TextChanged += (sender, e) => OnEditorCommentTextChanged(question, editor.Text);

            frame.Content = editor;
            stackGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);

            stackGrid.Children.Add(button);
            stackGrid.Children.Add(commentlabel, 0, 1);
            stackGrid.Children.Add(frame, 0, 2);
            commentStack.Children.Add(stackGrid);

            stack.Children.Add(commentStack);
            this.Children.Add(stack);


        private void OnButtonClicked(StackLayout stack)
    {
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IsVisible` property

```
stackGrid.IsVisible = !stackGrid.IsVisible;
```

Comment: Am I right by doing passing the commentStack to the button_onclicked and use this code?

Comment: Your question didn’t specify which element you wanted to hide.  Of course you should use the name of the appropriate element

Comment: works wonderfully, thank you so much!!